# JMeter - calculate variable using another variable

Tags: jmeter

I have 5 thread groups and I want the number of threads in each group to be derived from a total users number.

So I wouldn't need to change the numbers in each thread group every time I change the number of users.

So I defined 6 variables on my test plan:

```
 1. TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_USERS = ${__P(num_of_users,100)}
 2. WEIGHT_OF_GROUP_1 = ${__P(weight1,0.2)}
 3. ...
 4. ...
 5. ... 
 6. WEIGHT_OF_GROUP_6 = ${__P(weight6,0.2)}
```

and than in the thread group `Number of threads(users)` field I put - `${WEIGHT_OF_GROUP_1}*${TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_USERS}`.

When I start the test plan I can see in the log that the number of threads was interpreted as `0`.

I tried using `evalVar` or doing the calculation at the place where I define the variables, but it didn't work.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [__BeanShell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function if you need computations:

Comment: Thanks - BeanShell did solve the problem. The problem that I had was that it didn't seem to handle 0.2 - so I did WEIGHT_OF_GROUP_6=20 and the script is ${__BeanShell(${__evalVar(TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_USERS)}*${__evalVar(WEIGHT_OF_GROUP_6)}/100)} and every thing works now